# google-bigquery Schedule a nightly table copy

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a scheduled job / process to copy a bigquery table each night?  I am trying to create automated nightly table backups, and I havent seen any examples of how to accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

You can use bq query tool to submit batch job and schedule it with cron (or Task Scheduler if on Windows). The command will look similar to this:

`bq --nosync query --batch --allow_large_results --nouse_legacy_sql --replace --destination_table dataset.backup_table  "select * from dataset.table"`